# SP problem in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

i got this error ,

When i execute this below sp snippet ,

> DROP PROCEDURE `get_DETAIL_STATE`//
>
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `get_DETAIL_STATE`(IN stateName VARCHAR(255))
> BEGIN
> sELECT cFname,cLname FROM med_patient WHERE cState = stateName;
> END
> DELIMITER ;

[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2715/probxc.jpg](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2715/probxc.jpg)

my updated snippet ,

> DELIMITER ;
> CREATE PROCEDURE get_DETAIL_STATE(IN stateName VARCHAR(255)) BEGIN SELECT cFname,cLname FROM med_patient WHERE cState = stateName; END ;

after issue i tried this snippet ,

Comment: DELIMITER ;
CREATE PROCEDURE get_DETAIL_STATE(IN stateName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT cFname,cLname FROM med_patient WHERE cState = stateName;
END ;
DELIMITER ;
   
Error like 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know what `//` is, so it considers it a syntax error.

I suspect you forgot to change the delimiter from the default `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined delimiter?

```
delimiter //
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[screenshot http://fotos.fotoflexer.com/14f84650413ab50bfd76ccf48db783a8.jpg](http://fotos.fotoflexer.com/14f84650413ab50bfd76ccf48db783a8.jpg)

Please make sure you change the delimiter in the delimiter text box as shown in the above picture.